# Binary division correction from the textbook

Tags: binary, binary-operations

One example is from a textbook. It performs a binary division, though I think they made a mistake in their calculations? Also, another one is a solution that I tried working out, but I also think they made a mistake. The answer that I think is wrong is highlighted in yellow. I worked out the subtraction by getting the 2's complementary. I'm pretty sure I did the 2's complementary right. [image: Textbook]

[image: Here is another problem solution]

Comment: If it is a mistake, then there already was an analogous one in the third line ($1010-1001$)

Comment: It's polynomial division. I figured it out. Thanks.